# Как добавить свой пункт меню в админки OpenCart 2.0

Tags: php, cms, opencart

Помогите кто знает, кок можно выводить свой пункт меню в админке opencart 2.0 [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Через модуль куда покопаться возможно есть какой нибудь метод для добавления своего меню?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите контроллер `admin/controller/common/menu.php` и файл представления

```
admin/view/template/common/menu.tpl
```

Для того чтобы добавить новый пункт меню:

1) В контроллере

`$data['my_menu_item'] = $this->url->link('/* Здесь ссылка на ваш контроллер. Например catalog/my_module */', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');`

2) В файле представления в нужном Вам месте меню

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $my_menu_item; ?>">Название пункта меню</a></li>
```

Comment: Да вот какраз меню нашел спасибо, а как можно вообще манипулировать (добавит) через свой модуль свой массив с меню, в этот контролер и выводит в представления?

Comment: отредактировал ответ

Comment: А нельзя ли не трогая `admin/controller/common/menu.php` и `admin/view/template/common/menu.tpl` это сделать, я как то помню в сторонних модулях было сделано как то.

Comment: Суть модуля состоит в том, что он не внедряет свой код напрямую в контроллер. Он просто указывает куда нужно добавить/изменить код и при подключении модуля движок создает копию нужного файла и вносит туда изменения, которые указаны инструкцией модуля. То есть оригинальный файл не изменяется, а используется его копия. Вы можете написать свой модуль и внести с его помощью изменения в нужные контроллер и файл представления, если не хотите трогать файлы движка.

Comment: -"А нельзя ли не трогая..." Что бы вот так уж совсем не ничего не трогать, но при  этом что бы что-нибудь было, почитайте про events. https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=cms/blog/info&blog_id=174 https://nikita-sp.com.ua/2015/12/sistema-sobyitiy-opencart-2-ispolzovat-event.html https://freecart.pro/forum/blogs/entry/12-sistema-sobyitiy-event-v-opencart-chast-1-iz-3-obrabotka-sobyitiy/ (just google it)